# How to sort an hash Reference in perl by descending/ascending values and ascending/descending keys?

Tags: perl, sorting

my hash reference  to an hash  looks something like this

```
my %hey = (
    144 => 'Abc_test1',
    25  => 'sample2',
    114 => 'User',
    145 => 'abc_test2',
);
```

I want output order as

```
Abc_test1  
User
abc_test2
sample2
```

which I should be able to store in some variable

Any help?

Comment: `foreach my $value (sort {$a <=> $b} values %hey) {
    say $value;
}`. You can easily store them in an array by replacing `say $value` with `push(@array, $value);` ( dont forget to declare `@array` before the `foreach`.

Comment: @JohnDoe I would add it as an answer

Comment: As I see you want 2 methods of sorting which are nicely explained [here](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-sort-a-hash-in-perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort is using an expression to work out what order to sort things in, so it's not limited to just comparing one thing. In your case you want something like this...

```
my @sorted_values = map $hey{$_}, sort {$hey{$b} cmp $hey{$a} or $a <=> $b} keys %hey;
```

It firstly compares the values of the hash and sorts them in descending order. In the case where the two values are identical, it then compares the key values and sorts in ascending order.

Comment: No packages required. Will need the hash name changed if it isn't `%hey` as per your question.

Comment: Doesn't work for me..Does it require any explicit packages?  Because my error log shows that it is missing explicit package names.   But It's working fine in generalized examples.   what if I interchange keys and values in my hash? would your code work fine even then?

Comment: Sorry My bad!! My hash is actually an reference,Can you modify your code accordingly?

Comment: Can you modify the question accordingly too? Otherwise my answer doesn't fit the question

Comment: I did modify it a bit...and don't remove this answer.It's helping me in other things

Comment: Can I sort using exceptions? Like I want "User" to display on top always and the remaining pairs should be sorted accordingly

Comment: If you can express that exception as an expression, then yes; something like `($hey{$a} eq "User") <=> ($hey{$b} eq "User") ` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
values=[sort {$a<=>$b and $hey->{$a} cmp $hey->{$b}} keys  %$hey],
```